# How to both animate and use different animation for the whileInView with Framer Motion?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I want Nav to appear 1 second delayed for the first animation, and non-delayed for the next ones.

I defined both animate and whileInView separately in variants, and gave each on the element respectively. But whileInView takes over in precedence so animate animation never happens. How can I fix that?

```
const navVariants = {
  hidden: { y: -100 },
  animate: { y: 0, transition: { delay: 1, duration: 1 } },
  whileInView: { y: 0, transition: { duration: 1 } },
}

<Nav
      variants={navVariants}
      initial="hidden"
      animate="animate"
      whileInView="whileInView"
    >
...
```